# For the given function examine the continuity and differentiability at $(0,0)$

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

$$
f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            x^2 -x\sqrt{y} & \quad (x,y)\neq (0,0) \\
            0 & \quad (x,y)=(0,0)
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

Consider a curve $y=m^2x^2$.

Then $$f\left(x,m^2x^2\right) = \frac{x^2-mx^2}{x^2+m^2x^2}
                  = \frac{1-m}{1+m^2}$$

since limit of the function is dependent upon $m$ and hence dependent upon the path therefore the the function is not continuous at $(0,0)$.

Now I am unable to examine the differentiability of the function.

Comment: What is $f(1,-1)$?

Comment: Try moving along the $x$ axis for the limit.

Comment: f(1,-1) not defined as y must be a positive number

Comment: If a function isn’t continuous at a point, then it’s not differentiable there either.

Comment: okay got it.... thanks joe